# .h generated from .h.in?

Tags: header, autoconf, shtool

There are struct definitions in the .h file that my library creates after I build it.. but I cannot find these in the corresponding .h.in. Can somebody tell me how all this works and where it gets the extra info from?

To be specific: I am building pth, the userspace threading library. It has pth_p.h.in, which doesn't contain the struct definition I am looking for, yet when I build the library, a pth_p.h appears and it has the definition I need.

In fact, I have searched every single file in the library before it is built and cannot find where it is generating the struct definition.

Comment: May I ask for a reference about `.h.in`? Where that comes from?

Answer (score 2):

Pth uses GNU [Autoconf](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Autoconf), [Automake](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Automake), and [Libtool](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Libtool).  By running `./configure` you'll be running a shell script which eventually runs [m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) to detect the presence of a whole bunch of different system attributes and make changes to a number of files.

It looks like it boils down to `./configure` generating `Makefile` from `Makefile.in` and then running something via make that triggers the [`shtool`](http://www.gnu.org/software/shtool/) subcommand `scpp`:

```
pth_p.h: $(S)pth_p.h.in
    $(SHTOOL) scpp -o pth_p.h -t $(S)pth_p.h.in -Dcpp -Cintern -M '==#==' $(HSRCS)
```

Obscure link, but here's an [shtool-scpp manpage](http://je.je/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+shtool-scpp), which describes it as:

> This command is an additional ANSI C
>   source file pre-processor for sharing
>   cpp(1) code segments, internal
>   variables and internal functions. The
>   intention for this comes from writing
>   libraries in ANSI C. Here a common
>   shared internal header file is usually
>   used for sharing information between
>   the library source files.
>
> The operation is to parse special
>   constructs in files, generate a few
>   things out of these constructs and
>   insert them at position mark in tfile
>   by writing the output to ofile.
>   Additionally the files are never
>   touched or modified. Instead the
>   constructs are removed later by the
>   cpp(1) phase of the build process. The
>   only prerequisite is that every file
>   has a ``"#include ""ofile"""'' at the
>   top.

Comment: Close, but not quite. `m4` is used to compile `configure.ac` or `configure.in` (deprecated) into `./configure`, which is a shell script that runs the whole pile of tests. I'd never seen shtool-scpp before and I'm not sure if I like it or hate it. It's certainly cool, though.

Comment: May I ask for a reference about `.h.in`? Where that comes from?

Answer (score 0):

.h.in is probably processed within a configure (generated from configure.ac) script, look out for

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([thatfile.h])
```

It replaces variables of the form `@VAR@` in the `.in` file with their values.

Edit: Just noticed if I'm right you should retag your question

Comment: May I ask for a reference about `.h.in`? Where that comes from?