# In MongoDB source code, how to generate src/mongo/config.h from src/mongo/config.h.in?

Tags: mongodb

I'm studying MongoDB by reading the source code. But there is no config.h file, instead there is a config.h.in file. I know that the config.h file needs to be generated by the config.h.in file, but I don't know how to do. Can anyone tell me how to do, or send me a config.h file content directly. My operating system is macOS.

Comment: Do you like to study C++ or MongoDB? If you study MongoDB then I would rather recommend https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/?searchProperty=current

Comment: I want to learn the design principles of MongoDB, not just how to use it. So I chose to read the MongoDB source code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.h generated from .h.in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483000/h-generated-from-h-in)